# cmd error while using python code

Tags: python, cmd

I am new to the process of learning programming. So I am going to learn Python for my first scripting language. I downloaded Python 3.6.2 and wrote the simple "hello world " program in IDLE- it works just fine

And then I tried to open the file in command prompt and it was showing a syntax error as the below.

```
C:\Users\User>cd \Code

C:\Users\User>cd \Code

C:\Code>
C:\Code>hello.py


  File "C:\Code\hello.py", line 1


 Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^


SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Code>
```

my pc is a windows 10 and 64 bits

I searched for the solution and I couldn't find any.
Please reply me if you have a solution

thank you!!

Comment: Post your Python code. Try running your script with the Python interpreter, i.e. `python hello.py`

Comment: yeah i did the same in the interpreter but the result is same

Comment: first i opened cmd in windows

and then changed the directory into folder i save the files
cd \Code

and then

it shows C:\Code>
then I type "python hello.py"

and the result is same :(

Comment: You appear to have copied the Python interactive header into your `hello.py` file. This is your first problem, but if you're new enough to do that and not realize anything is wrong, you likely have more problems.

Comment: So how can I resolve it? I am totally clueless. Well the code is working in IDLE but not in CMD @ user2357112

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that you are running from the command line. Clearly there is something wrong with the Python script but it's hard to advise without seeing the code.

Comment: @pinky:  I don't see any Python code in your question. As @user2357112 noted you appear to have added the Python header to your code. That is not valid Python, so you get the syntax error. Check your `hello.py` file and add it to your question if you actually want help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Windows cmd, but in Linux, we usually run python from terminal as

```
python3 filename.py
```

or make filename.py an executable and run ./filename.py

Answer (score 0):

when you want to run a python file using cmd, you have to prefix `python` to execute your program.
In this case, type `python hello.py` and see the magic!

Comment: No, you do not need to explicitly run `python`, not unless you've changed the default .py file association to an IDE or text editor.